# Error Logging options in Angular application without depending on backend framework

Tags: angular

What are possible ways of logging errors in Angular application without depending on the backend RestAPI calls/framework? In my case, as a UI developer I don't want to rely on backend team to capture and log error. Instead would like to know possible ways to log in UI.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to log the errors from the UI itself. I guess you could use something like ngx-logger package to do that kind of logging.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-logger

Another thing to try you can create some kind of logging service inside angular application which will log the errors that you are getting. For this I will suggest you follow this article
https://www.codemag.com/article/1711021/Logging-in-Angular-Applications

You can try also creating HTTP Interceptors for catching the errors. If you dont know how to do that please follow the angular-university blog for that.

https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/

The last and I think the best thing to work with is sentry.io, which will give you performance bottlenecks and errors tracking.

https://sentry.io/for/angular/

Answer (score 0):

Use interceptor for error handling

```
import {
 HttpEvent,
 HttpInterceptor,
 HttpHandler,
 HttpRequest,
 HttpResponse,
 HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private toastr: ToastrService, private router: Router) {}
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   return next.handle(request)
     .pipe(
       retry(1),
       catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        console.log("Error Event");
      } else {
        console.log(
          `error status : ${error.status} ${JSON.stringify(error.error)}`
        );
        switch (error.status) {
          case 401:
            this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
            break;
          case 403:
            this.router.navigateByUrl("/unauthorized");
            break;
          case 0:
          case 400:
          case 405:
          case 406:
          case 409:
          case 500:
            this.handleAuthError(error);
            break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.error("something else happened");
    }

    return throwError(error);
       })
     )
 }
public handleAuthError(error: any) {
    console.log("error ", error);
    let msg = "";
    if (error !== undefined && typeof error === "string") {
      msg = error;
    } else if (error.error !== undefined && typeof error.error === "string") {
      msg = error.error;
    } else if (
      error.error.error !== undefined &&
      typeof error.error.error === "string"
    ) {
      msg = error.error.error;
    } else {
      msg = error.error.error.errors
        ? error.error.error.errors[0].errorMessage
        : "Something went wrong";
    }
    this.toastr.error(msg, "", {
      timeOut: 3000,
      positionClass: "toast-bottom-center",
    });
  }
}
```

add this tag in **app.module.ts**

```
providers: [
   {
     provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
     useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor,
     multi: true
   }
 ]
```